# Applying multiple functions to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to apply multiple functions to a dataframe column in R as shown below:

`lapply(targets$phenotype, function(x) {tolower(x); gsub(" ", "_",x) })`

However, only the second one ends up running. Same thing happens if I switch the order of tolower and gsub (only the second one runs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tolower` is not updated to `x`

```
lapply(targets$phenotype, function(x) {x <- tolower(x); gsub(" ", "_",x) })
```

---

here, we don't even need a loop if it is a single column as `gsub` and `tolower` are vectorized

```
targets$phenotype <- gsub(" ", "_", tolower(targets$phenotype))
```